# How to use the proxy for API call

Tags: uno-platform

I'm using System.Net.Http.HttpClient to call some API.

It works correctly in UWP

It fails in WASM with the error : "Operation is not supported on this platform."

Stack trace show this is System.Net.WebProxy.CreateDefaultProxy() that fails.

What is the most universal way to do API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the best way to handle this is to set the default handler to Uno's `WasmHttpHandler`, as follows:

```
var httpMessageHandler = Type
    .GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpClient, System.Net.Http")
    .GetField("GetHttpMessageHandler",
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic
    );

httpMessageHandler.SetValue(
    null,
    (Func<HttpMessageHandler>)(() => new Uno.UI.Wasm.WasmHttpHandler())
);
```

Note that this does not override the default `HttpHandler` behavior, which means that if you use it explicitly, you'll get the same error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I'l use the WasmHttpHandler directly.